# CSS or jQuery getting items _with_ first-child of a certain type

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

Is there a way in either CSS (IE7+) or jQuery to select items whose first-child has a particular type, such that like the following pseudocode, you would be able to select all *li* with a first child *a*:

```
li:first-child(a)
```

**Update**

I was looking for the solution @SLaks suggested, because I wanted to get it in one selector. However the .parent() method is faster, see: http://jsfiddle.net/c4urself/Qw8fX/

```
$("li > a:first-child").parent()
```

vs.

```
$("li:has(>a:first-child)")
```

**Update 2**

See performance differences between the two methods here at jsPerf

http://jsperf.com/jquery-has-child-vs-parent-child-and-parent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS can't do this, but jQuery can:

```
li:has(>a:first-child)
```

CSS cannot do this because CSS was designed to be applied in a forward-only manner as the browser reads the HTML.  It is always possible to determine which CSS rules apply to an element *immediately*, without waiting for the element's children or subsequent siblings.

Comment: Awesome! exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

in jQuery `$('ul li a:first-child').parent();`

Comment: Thanks, I'm going for @SLaks's suggestion as it directly selects the li's without having to call .parent().

Comment: @c4urself: I would guess that this is somewhat faster.  If you switch, measure it first.  If you do, please tell me; I'm curious (but lazy)

Comment: I thought so.  `:has` is one of the slowest selectors, since it needs to search the descendant tree and it cannot use `querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the li:first-child psuedo class you could apply the required style to the li item that would then style the a that was nested inside it. Take a look at http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-firstchild

Comment: Thanks! That's the normal :first-child selector, I was looking for something that selects the li's themselves

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible in CSS, but in jQuery you'd want to use `filter()`.

Make sure you filter based on `contents()`, not `children()` since you'll want to see text nodes.

```
$( function() {   
  $('li').filter( function() {
    return $(this).contents().first().is('a');
  }).each( function() {
    $('body').append($(this).text() + '<br/>');
  });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/olufan

It takes up a bit more code than doing it all in a jQuery selector, but performance should be much better. jQuery selectors only really work fast when specifying a single term.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for a simple selection of the li though, see @SLaks implementation.